# Include multiple headers in python requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I have this HTTPS call in curl below;

```
header1="projectName: zhikovapp"
header2="Authorization: Bearer HZCdsf="
bl_url="https://BlazerNpymh.com/api/documents?pdfDate=$today"

curl -s -k -H "$header1" -H "$header2" "$bl_url"
```

I would like to write an equivalent python call using requests module.

```
header ={
            "projectName": "zhikovapp",
            "Authorization": "Bearer HZCdsf="
        }
response = requests.get(bl_url, headers = header)
```

However, the request was not valid. What is wrong?

The contents of the returned response is like this;

```
<Response [400]>
_content = '{"Message":"The request is invalid."}'
headers = {'Content-Length': '37', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'projectname, authorization, Content-Type', 'Expires': '-1', 'cacheControlHeader': 'max-age=604800', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Sat, 15 Oct 2016 02:41:13 GMT', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
reason = 'Bad Request'
```

I am using python 2.7

EDIT: I corrected some syntex errors after Soviut pointed them out.

Comment: What result did you get? My guess is you got a syntax error.

Comment: try curl version and your code with url `http://httpbin.org/get`. It sends back all headers and then you can compare headers in both version

Comment: Is the actual url you are using public?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In `request.get()` the [`headers`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers) argument should be defined as a dictionary, a set of key/value pairs. You've defined a set (a unique list) of strings instead.

You should declare your headers like this:

```
headers = {
    "projectName": "zhikovapp",
    "Authorization": "Bearer HZCdsf="
}
response = requests.get(bl_url, headers=headers)
```

Note the `"key": "value"` format of each line inside the dictionary.

Edit: Your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` say they'll accept `projectname` and `authorization` in lower case. You've named your header `projectName` and `Authorization` with upper case letters in them. If they don't match, they'll be rejected.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but I still get the same error.

Comment: What error? Please post it in your original question.

Comment: Thanks. I have posted on the question and corrected the syntax error as you pointed out.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more detail regarding your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` error.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you have `$today` defined in the shell you make  `curl` call from, and you don't substitute it in the `requests`' call URL, then it's a likely reason for the *400 Bad Request*.
2. `Access-Control-*` and other CORS headers have nothing to do with non-browser clients. Also HTTP headers are generally case insensitive.
3. Following @furas's advice here's the output:

   ```
   $ curl -H "projectName: zhikovapp" -H "Authorization: Bearer HZCdsf=" \
       http://httpbin.org/get

   {
      "args": {}, 
      "headers": {
         "Accept": "*/*", 
         "Authorization": "Bearer HZCdsf=", 
         "Host": "httpbin.org", 
         "Projectname": "zhikovapp", 
         "User-Agent": "curl/7.35.0"
      }, 
      "origin": "1.2.3.4", 
      "url": "http://httpbin.org/get"
   }
   ```

   And the same request with `requests`:

   ```
   import requests
   res = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get', headers={
     "projectName"   : "zhikovapp",
     "Authorization" : "Bearer HZCdsf="
   })
   print(res.json())

   {
     'args': {},
     'headers': {
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer HZCdsf=',
        'Host': 'httpbin.org',
        'Projectname': 'zhikovapp',
        'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/3.4.3 '
          'Linux/3.16.0-38-generic'
      },
      'origin': '1.2.3.4',
      'url': 'http://httpbin.org/get'
   }
   ```

   As you can see the only difference is `User-Agent` header. It's unlikely the cause but you can easily set it in `headers` to the value you like.