# Grafana 10.1 API: cannot create an organization

Tags: grafana, admin, organization

I want to create a Grafana organization through its API.

According to https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/org/

```
Create Organization
POST /api/orgs
Only works with Basic Authentication (username and password), see introduction.

Example Request:
POST /api/orgs HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
"name":"New Org."
}

Note: The api will work in the following two ways
Need to set GF_USERS_ALLOW_ORG_CREATE=true
Set the config value users.allow_org_create to true in ini file

Example Response:
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json

{
"orgId":"1",
"message":"Organization created"
}
```

I set up the following curl command:

```
curl \
-H "Accept: application/json, Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"name":"test"}' \
-u "admin:admin" \
-X POST \
http://localhost:3000/api/orgs
```

Its (bad) results is:
`{"message":"bad request data","traceID":""}`

My /etc/environnement:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
GF_USERS_ALLOW_ORG_CREATE="true"
```

My /etc/grafana/grafana.ini contains:

```
[users]

# disable user signup / registration

;allow_sign_up = true

# Allow non admin users to create organizations

;allow_org_create = true
users.allow_org_create = true
```

Note that any ";something" is a Grafana default that should not need to be set, from what I understood ...

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: You are using `-H` wrong. It should be `-H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: Thank you so much, it just works. 

I'm now trying to port it to Python3 with the following code (var url includes the http:// protocol) ;
url = 'http://admin:admin@localhost:3000/api/orgs'
data= {'name': 'test}
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url,data,headers)

... and I get the same bad results  {"message":"bad request data","traceID":""}

I sould be right according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40054357/include-multiple-headers-in-python-requests ... but once again I'm lost ...

Comment: This is out of my field of expertise, but I believe you passing parameters into `post` incorrectly. `data` and `headers` supposed to be used as named parameters. Try `requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. You're right, they are named parameters, and I corrected my code accordingly. Sadly, I'm still stuck with the same error message ... trying to fix it :)

Comment: You need either to use `json=` instead of `data=`, or convert your dictionary to string. So either `..., json={"name":"wwasasdd"}, headers={...` or `..., data='{"name":"wwasasdd"}', headers={...`

Comment: I finally opted for subprocess in Python so as to call curl and it all works nicely :)  Nevertheless, I gave a try to your idea, but it did not work ... still I guess you're once again on the way of finding the solution :) Thank you!